# How to direct the client to different pages based on a condition from a previous page?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm making a website for my college where students, staff and the secretaries can log in. Each category of these people will go to the page named `index.html` where they will be provided with a form with a username and password field. Now every category has a particular pattern of username; for eg the students have their ID number as their username, the staff have their names as username and the secretaries have their department as their username. When they enter the login credentials and submit, then they will be redirected to their particular pages. I've created 3 pages: `student.html`, `staff.html` and `secretary.html`. And I want to redirect each of these to their respective pages. For eg if someone is a student, then he/she will be redirected to `student.html` and so. Ofcourse I have to check the username before proceeding to know what among the 3 category the client belongs to, but I don't know the other part - the part of directing them to their particular pages based on the condition.

Comment: I would suggest revising if you need 3 pages. Instead I would have one page that includes other components based on category. Let's say you have menu, body and footer. Have student_menu, staff_menu and secretary_menu. Same for body. I would assume they share the footer. After the login. Redirect to home.php which includes which menu and body based on category. No need to replicate data in multiple pages. Should you do that, make sure you check if someone viewing staff.html is actually a staff not a student playing with url.

Answer (score 0):

When someone is logging in, you already know which category he belongs to right?
So you should just redirect him to that category page. Something like this:

```
$redirect_to = $category . ".html"`; // decide which page i.e: 'staff.html'
header('Location: ' . $redirect_to); // redirect him to that page
```

See the [php header documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a prefix to the *ids* would be easier to create the redirect logic.

After authenticating a user session and use `header` to redirect e.g:

```
<?php
   // you logic auth here...

   /* this example assumes that the pages to be redirected are in the same
      directory and defines three ids fictitious ($id) e.g:

      students    id: student-1231vjhj32v123h123gh

      staffs      id: staff-chuck-norris

      secretaries id: secretary-office

   */

    if(preg_match('/student/i', $id) ){
       //redirect
       header('Location: student.html');
    }

    if(preg_match('/staff/i', $id) ){
       //redirect
       header('Location: staff.html');
    }

    if(preg_match('/secretary/i', $id) ){
       //redirect
       header('Location: secretary.html');
    }
```